# Google Sheets - View Only Access to Protected Workbook But Allow Use of Dropdowns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Every month we upload excel files to goole drive and convert them to google sheets for use by senior management.  The process is locked in so I can not change anything here.  Access is granted to the users at a folder level, with them all only getting view access, it's very important that they cannot edit the files.  We are uploading several files, but they are all the exact same layout just showing numbers for different departments.  I'd like to change this to be just one file, with a dropdown to select the department, there are no issues with anyone seeing the numbers from any other department.

I've tried using the below app script to allow the users to use the dropdowns, but it only works if they have edit access.

```
function ProtectSheet(){
// Protect the active sheet except the dropdowns, then remove all other users from 
the list of editors.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Sample protected sheet');
var unprotected = sheet.getRange('A4:L4');
protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected]);
// Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the 
user's edit
// permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing 
the group.
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
}}
```

1. Is there anything I can do that would allow them to use dropdowns in the workbook but also only have view or comment access?
2. Is there anyway the above code can be applied to an entire workbook rather than having to add it to each tab?

Comment: 1. No, the alternative to change your approach. 2. The code is not limited to a single tab. What make you think that? P.S. Questions on this site should specific, meaning only one question per post.

Comment: 1. Can you advise on a better approach?
2. When I was testing the code, if I didn't run it on each tab the test user had complete access.

My whole question resolves around how to make the code I have work for my scenario, not sure how I am asking multiple questions?